# How to fix "The web application [myapp] appears to have started a thread named [HikariPool-113 housekeeper] but has failed to stop it"?

Tags: spring-boot, tomcat, jdbc, memory-leaks, hikaricp

I'm running a Spring Boot project, I have a method that makes a call to an SQL Server database, it connects fine and returns the results.

However, as I started re-deploying updates, this appears in the Tomcat logs:

```
==> catalina.2021-04-25.log <==
25-Apr-2021 09:05:45.307 WARNING [Catalina-utility-2] org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.clearReferencesJdbc The web application [ciamdev] registered the JDBC driver [com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver] but failed to unregister it when the web application was stopped. To prevent a memory leak, the JDBC Driver has been forcibly unregistered.
25-Apr-2021 09:05:45.309 WARNING [Catalina-utility-2] org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.clearReferencesThreads The web application [ciamdev] appears to have started a thread named [mssql-jdbc-shared-timer-core-0] but has failed to stop it. This is very likely to create a memory leak. Stack trace of thread:
 sun.misc.Unsafe.park(Native Method)
 java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.park(LockSupport.java:175)
 java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject.await(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:2039)
 java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$DelayedWorkQueue.take(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:1081)
 java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$DelayedWorkQueue.take(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:809)
 java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.getTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1074)
 java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1134)
 java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
 java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
25-Apr-2021 09:05:45.310 WARNING [Catalina-utility-2] org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.clearReferencesThreads The web application [ciamdev] appears to have started a thread named [HikariPool-113 housekeeper] but has failed to stop it. This is very likely to create a memory leak.
25-Apr-2021 09:05:45.312 WARNING [Catalina-utility-2] org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.clearReferencesThreads The web application [ciamdev] appears to have started a thread named [HikariPool-113 connection adder] but has failed to stop it. This is very likely to create a memory leak. Stack trace of thread:
```

Basically 4 main events:

```
com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver is forcibly removed
mssql-jdbc-shared-timer-core-0 thread was unable to shut down
HikariPool-113 housekeeper thread was unable to shut down
HikariPool-113 connection adder thread was unable to shut down
```

As I keep making calls to the database, and then re-deploying, the HikariPool threads start multiplying.

After some research I decided to try a solution involving ServletContextListener

I'll now post the relevant info/code:

This is the Tomcat version:

```
Using CATALINA_BASE:   /apps/tomcat/apache-tomcat-9.0.34
Using CATALINA_HOME:   /apps/tomcat/apache-tomcat-9.0.34
Using CATALINA_TMPDIR: /apps/tomcat/apache-tomcat-9.0.34/temp
Using JRE_HOME:        /usr
Using CLASSPATH:       /apps/tomcat/apache-tomcat-9.0.34/bin/bootstrap.jar:/apps/tomcat/apache-tomcat-9.0.34/bin/tomcat-juli.jar
Server version: Apache Tomcat/9.0.34
Server built:   Apr 3 2020 12:02:52 UTC
Server number:  9.0.34.0
OS Name:        Linux
OS Version:     3.10.0-1160.24.1.el7.x86_64
Architecture:   amd64
JVM Version:    1.8.0_275-b01
JVM Vendor:     Red Hat, Inc.
```

```
Apache Maven version 3.8.1
```

These are my pom.xml dependencies (which from another post I added the HikariCP exclusions tag):

```xml
    <dependencies>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
        </dependency>        

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.squareup.okhttp3</groupId>
            <artifactId>okhttp</artifactId>
            <version>3.11.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.jcraft</groupId>
            <artifactId>jsch</artifactId>
            <version>0.1.55</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.googlecode.json-simple</groupId>
            <artifactId>json-simple</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.microsoft.sqlserver</groupId>
            <artifactId>mssql-jdbc</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-jdbc</artifactId>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>com.zaxxer</groupId>
                    <artifactId>HikariCP</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>            
        </dependency>      

    </dependencies>
```

I created a Db class, where I instantiate the jdbcTemplate and add the datasource, and also implemented the ServletContextListener, it's this whole class where I'm sure I'm screwing up, here's the class:

```java
public class Db implements ServletContextListener {

  String message;

  @Override
  public void contextInitialized(ServletContextEvent servletContextEvent) {
    message = "contextInitialized\n\n";
    System.out.println("contextInitialized Server stopped");
  }

  @Override
  public void contextDestroyed(ServletContextEvent servletContextEvent) {
    message += "contextDestroyed\n\n";
    System.out.println("contextDestroyed Server stopped");

    Enumeration<Driver> drivers = DriverManager.getDrivers();
    while (drivers.hasMoreElements()) {
      Driver driver = drivers.nextElement();
      try {
        DriverManager.deregisterDriver(driver);
      } catch (SQLException e) {
        message += "ERROR(contextDestroyed): " + Utils.getStackTrace(e);
      }
    }
  }

  JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate;

  public Db() {
    jdbcTemplate = new JdbcTemplate(sqlServerDataSource());
  }

  @Bean(destroyMethod = "shutdownNow")
  private DataSource sqlServerDataSource() {
    DataSourceBuilder dataSourceBuilder = DataSourceBuilder.create();
    dataSourceBuilder.url(
      "jdbc:sqlserver://sbserver.net;databaseName=gg"
    );
    dataSourceBuilder.username("user");
    dataSourceBuilder.password("pass");
    return dataSourceBuilder.build();
  }

  public String runSome() {
    message = "From runSome: \n\n";

    try {
      message += "trying to execute jdbcTemplate...\n";
      String sql = "select * from gg.objecttypes";

      List<ObjectType> objectTypes = jdbcTemplate.query(
        sql,
        new BeanPropertyRowMapper(ObjectType.class)
      );

      message += "\n\n";
      for (final ObjectType objectType : objectTypes) {
        message +=
          objectType.getId() + " :: " + objectType.getObjecttype() + "\n";
      }

      message +=
        "::executed jdbcTemplate! " + objectTypes.size() + "\n";
    } catch (Exception e) {
      message += "ERROR(runSome): " + Utils.getStackTrace(e);
    }

    return message;
  }
}
```

I'm not even sure if the contextInitialized and contextDestroyed methods are executing.

I can then call the method from my controller:

```java
  @GetMapping(value = "/admin/user-health")
  public String userHealth() {

    String message = "From userHealth: \n\n";
    try {
        message += "trying to execute db.runSome()...\n";
        Db db = new Db();
        message += db.runSome();
        message += "executed db.runSome()!\n";
    } catch (Exception e) {
        message += "ERROR(userHealth): " + Utils.getStackTrace(e);
    }
    return message;

  }
```

Again, it works fine and I get the results from the database. Although eventually I get a connection timeout.

The problem is the memory leak because of threads that never die, and that I don't think I have user for.

How can I fix this?

Comment: _"I'm not even sure if the contextInitialized and contextDestroyed methods are executing."_: my guess is they are not. Did you register the `Db` class as `ServletContextListener` somewhere?

Comment: No I didn't. To give more context, I only really picked up Java and it's frameworks/plugins about 2 months ago, I had no choice, because of my job. So in this particular DB phase, I'm not really sure what I'm doing, I'd appreciate anyone offering some guidance.